Scene lighting looks very weird without any lights applied
I have a weird lighting and/or shading issue in a model of an interior I'm creating. When I started applying materials and uv-maps to the model, I noticed that only a small area in my scene seemed to be lit, the rest around this was dark grey. It's almost as if a powerful light source is lighting this small area. The effect persist even after I remove all lights from the scene. I have recalculated normals both inside and outside, and it has no effect.
I'm afraid I may have inadvertently changed something in my scene, perhaps by a key shortcut I wasn't aware of.
Does anyone know what might be the cause of this?


Do you have world? HDRI? Sky texture? These are sources of light. Material preview has HDRI

maybe the light is parented to an object and you don't see in the Outliner unless you check under the parent? Please share your file

I have removed any external libraries and light sources, but the issue persists. How can I share the blend file?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload

Thanks for replying, here is the file:


Please edit your question and add the full link directly into that. - Links in comments can easily be missed and the comment can even be deleted.

check the material, it is the procedural texture that creates a spot that looks like a light

It's not a light, it's your material. Check the material called Plaster - White, it is the procedural texture that creates a spot that looks like a light, select the node group and press Tab to have access to the nodes that create this procedural texture:



Thank you! that was indeed the problem.
